# Error performing DOM methods on Sizzle objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, sizzle

I'm giving Sizzle a try (without jQuery) for DOM selections. I'm mixing the Sizzle selections with native JS to build some animation functionality. I'm encountering errors when performing DOM methods on Sizzle objects. For example:

```
Sizzle('#masthead-copy').appendChild(foo);
```

Results in: `Object has no method 'appendChild'`. But the following works:

```
document.getElementById('masthead-copy').appendChild(foo);
```

The same occurs on similar methods throughout:

```
Sizzle('#masthead-images').getElementsByTagName('foo');
```

But the following works:

```
document.getElementById('masthead-images').getElementsByTagName('foo');
```

It seems Sizzle returns an Array on all selections (even on ids), which may explain the issue here. Is there a common workaround for this?

Comment: `Sizzle` will always return an Array. You would have the same problem if it returned a NodeList. You don't need a workaround. You just need to do what you'd always do with a collection. Use a loop.

Comment: @cookiemonster I don't need a loop for the examples above... if I drop `Sizzle` for the native DOM selections, everything works as is.

Comment: You mean for the `getElementById` examples? That's because that method doesn't return a collection. It returns a single node, so naturally there's no need to loop. If you're always fetching by ID, then just grab the first node in the collection.

Comment: So if `Sizzle` returns an Array for ids, I suppose I could reference them as `Sizzle('#masthead-images')[0]`?

Comment: What @cookiemonster says is true, Sizzle **always** returns an array, even if there's only one element.

Comment: Yes, if fetching by ID, just reference the first node in the collection.

Comment: The question is, why use Sizzle to get an element by ID

Comment: @adeneo It's part of a larger project and this is the simplest example of the issue.

Comment: @adeneo makes a good point, although Sizzle does fix a couple old IE6/7 bugs and an old Blackberry bug for `getElementById`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think this one's resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in comments, Sizzle returns an Array on all selections, and so selecting ids with Sizzle requires a reference to the first (only) item in the resulting array:

```
Sizzle('#masthead-copy')[0].appendChild(foo);
```